# how to connect a php exe to an online sql server using ZZEE PHPExe

Tags: php, mysql, database, compiler-construction, exe

i am trying to create a *php.exe* file using **ZZEE PHPExe** but my problem is that my **database is hosted online** from **justhost**, when i try to connect using the compiled *php.exe* it always gives me *errors*, *i wasn't able to connect to my database at justhost*, is there any php compiler that will **allow me to connect to my online database**? what will be the best choice for a compiler ?